# Configure Mapstruct on VSCode for JUnit5

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5, mapstruct

I'm trying to configure a project to run a unit test for mapstruct, I'm using:

java 8
spring boot 2.6.3
gradle
junit 5
Lombok
mapstruct
vs code

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {UsersMapperImpl.class })
```

It works perfectly fine when I run Gradle test or Gradle build, but on compile time I get an error:
UsersMapperImpl cannot be resolved to a type

The name of the class is UsersMapper.java
Is there a configuration I'm missing? I'm trying to use ContextConfiguration.

I expect to solve compile time error